# Can I ask about how to manage a page on Facebook?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a group on Facebook, and currently it is a closed group. However, I want to open it up so that other people can see what the group are doing, but restrict who can/can't post on the page.

Can I ask about this on SE?

Comment: There's a difference between Pages and Groups. Be sure you don't conflate the two.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) site where [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) is the 3rd-largest tag. (Searching first is recommended, as usual.)

Comment: The tags [facebook-pages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pages) and/or [facebook-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-groups) may also be appropriate.